# Почему парсер на Telethon не реагирует на сообщения из чужих каналов?

Tags: python, парсер, telegram-bot, telegram, telethon

Всем добрый день!
Я пробую написать Telegram-бота, который бы собирал новые сообщения из заданного списка каналов, и пересылал их в мой канал (где я администратор). Для этого я использую библиотеку Telethon.
Если я пишу сообщение в своём же канале, то бот его спокойно пересылает. Но на сообщения из чужих каналов вообще никак не реагирует. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем это может быть связано?

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from config import DESTINATION, API_ID, API_HASH, SESSION, CHATS


client = TelegramClient(SESSION, API_ID, API_HASH)
client.start()

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=CHATS))
async def main(event):
    print('Delivery new order...')
    await event.forward_to(DESTINATION)

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Answer (score 0):

скорее всего - ограничения телеграмма, telethon не читает новые сообщения в каналах от 500 подписчиков(https://qna.habr.com/q/1106974).Я тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой и буду искать пути её решения, если найду, то отпишусь.

Answer (score 0):

Я подписан на те каналы, с которых юзер-бот собирает сообщения.
У меня эта проблема решилась таким образом.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не задавайте уточняющих вопросов в тексте ответа, для этого есть комментарии.

Comment: @МихаилРебров почему не является ответом? Правкой я убрал вопросительную форму.